Assign a Custom User Role Upon WooCommerce Subscription Activation
In WooCommerce, I need to automatically assign a custom role ("Active Production Company") to users upon their subscription becoming active. The role assignment will allow only active subscribers to access and submit a restricted form on the site, created with WP Job Manager.
I’ve added a WooCommerce subscription product (monthly and yearly) for users to purchase, which grants them the custom role upon successful payment.
Here’s the code I’m currently using:
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_updated', 'wc_subscribe_assign_role', 10, 3 );

function wc_subscribe_assign_role( $subscription, $new_status, $old_status ) {
   if ( $new_status === 'active' ) {
       $user_id = $subscription->get_user_id(); // Get the user ID of the subscriber
       $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
        
        // Assign the "Active Production Company" role upon subscription activation
        $user->set_role( 'active_production_company' );
    }
}

I’m not certain if $subscription is being used correctly to get the user ID, or if woocommerce_subscription_status_updated is the best hook for this purpose.
I used the woocommerce_subscription_status_updated hook, hoping it would trigger role assignment upon a subscription’s status change to "active." I expected this to automatically assign the "Active Production Company" role to users, allowing them to access the restricted form.
After testing with a test order, the expected role was not applied. I checked the WooCommerce subscription object documentation and my error logs but couldn’t confirm if the $subscription->get_user_id() part was working as intended. I’d appreciate any insights or suggestions for achieving this functionality reliably!

Note that the WC_Subscription Object inherits methods from WC_Abstract_Order and WC_Order classes, so you can use either:

get_user() method, to get the WP_User object,
get_user_id() method, to get the user ID.

Now you can better use woocommerce_subscription_status_active composite filter hook, that is triggered when a subscription become active.
Note that you should add your custom role instead of replacing the current user role(s), as a subscriber role is assigned and used by WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin.
Here is a simplified code version:
// Add "Active Production Company" role upon subscription activation
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_active', 'add_role_to_active_subscribers', 10 );
function add_role_to_active_subscribers( $subscription ) {
    $custom_role =  'active_production_company'; // Custom user role to add
    $user = $subscription->get_user(); // Get the WP User object
 
    // If user has not yet the custom user role
    if( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) && ! in_array(  $custom_role, (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        $user->add_role( $custom_role ); // Add custom role
    }
}

It should work.
If you really wish, you can always use set_role() method instead of add_role().

I have used this function before and it is not working. so i checked in php myadmin table and i am unable to find data in phpmyadmin while in wordpress dashboard subscription is getting saved while on the other hand, no table having data of subscription. what is issue

Try to enable WP Debug as explained in HERE and use error_log('Subscription active'); inside the function, to check if the hook is triggered when a subscription gets active. Now
you say "…while on the other hand, no table having data of subscription…": Note that in WooCommerce, High Performance Order Storage is now enabled by default, so orders and subscriptions data are now located in WooCommerce custom tables.
